# Listview alternative 2

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need you to find the best way for build my view.

This is a page listing questions : I can use a listview, BUT,
The problem is :

- Questions can be deleted
- Questions can be added
- Questions can be modified
  ..and the order can be changed.

I also thought to simulate a listview by adding fragment.
Can i make this method without weigh down the view ?

Thank you in advance for your ideas!

Bryan

Comment: How do any of those "problems" prevent you from using a ListView?

Comment: Then use a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) to implement that.